# MySQL Get duration between gaps

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the duration where a unit was not at 100%.

```
|ID| DATE               | UNITNAME | PERCENTAGE|  
------------------------------------------------
|1 |2018-01-20 00:00:00 | UNIT1    |100        |
|2 |2018-01-20 00:05:00 | UNIT1    |0          |
|3 |2018-01-20 00:10:00 | UNIT1    |100        |
|4 |2018-01-20 00:15:00 | UNIT1    |99         | 
|5 |2018-01-20 00:20:00 | UNIT1    |50         |
|6 |2018-01-20 00:25:00 | UNIT1    |100        |
```

So in this I would expect the output similar to:

```
| UNITNAME | RPO         |
| UNIT1    | 00:15:00    |
```

The unit reported at 00:05:00 as 0%, then the next interval at 00:10:00 it was 100%. So i will assume the unit was out of RPO for 5mins. This occurs again at 00:15:00 until 00:25:00 so will assume this was out for the entire period.

I've looked aroud and manged to create the follow on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/997e14/1/0)
using the below;

```
select UNITNAME, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) as 'RPO'
from(
      SELECT UNITNAME, TIMEDIFF(MAX(DATE), MIN(DATE)) AS duration, MIN(DATE) AS 
startime, MAX(DATE) AS endtime
FROM (
    SELECT 
tp.*
, @val_change := IF(@prev_val != Percentage, @val_change+1 , @val_change) AS vc
, @prev_val := Percentage
FROM
Replication_History tp 
, (SELECT @prev_val := NULL, @val_change := 0) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY UNITNAME, DATE
 ) sq
 WHERE Percentage =100 
 GROUP BY UNITNAME, vc
 )ts
 group by UNITNAME
```

This kind of works, but does not correctly mange the gaps between 100%.

As anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using the 'Gaps-and-islands' approach:

```
SELECT UNITNAME,  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) AS PRO
FROM (
   SELECT UNITNAME, TIMEDIFF(MAX(DATE), MIN(DATE)) AS duration
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, DATE, UNITNAME, Percentage,
             @rn := IF(@unit = UNITNAME, IF(Percentage = 100, @rn + 1, @rn),
                       IF(@unit := UNITNAME, 1, 1)) AS grp
      FROM replication_history
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @unit := '', @rn := 0) AS v
      ORDER BY UNITNAME, DATE DESC) AS t
   GROUP BY UNITNAME, grp
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Percentage <> 100 THEN 1 END) > 0) AS u
GROUP BY UNITNAME
```

To understand how this query works you have to execute the innermost subquery and examine the results it produces.

So, this query:

```
SELECT ID, DATE, UNITNAME, Percentage, grp
FROM (
    SELECT ID, DATE, UNITNAME, Percentage,
         @rn := IF(@unit = UNITNAME, IF(Percentage = 100, @rn + 1, @rn),
                   IF(@unit := UNITNAME, 1, 1)) AS grp
    FROM replication_history
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @unit := '', @rn := 0) AS v
    ORDER BY UNITNAME, DATE DESC) AS t
ORDER BY UNITNAME, DATE
```

produces the following output:

```
 ID,    DATE,                UNITNAME, Percentage, grp
-------------------------------------------------------
204200, 2018-01-20 10:00:00, UNIT1,    100,        3
204201, 2018-01-20 10:05:00, UNIT1,    0,          2
204202, 2018-01-20 10:10:00, UNIT1,    100,        2
204203, 2018-01-20 10:15:00, UNIT1,    99,         1
204204, 2018-01-20 10:20:00, UNIT1,    50,         1
204205, 2018-01-20 10:25:00, UNIT1,    100,        1
```

So, as you can see for the above data, `grp` field identifies 'out of PRO' intervals. Groups having only `100` as percentage value are filtered out by the second level subquery.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fae91/3)

Answer (score 2):

Is it simply the sum of the difference between these values...

```
SELECT a.unitname
     , MIN(a.date) my_start
     , a.min_date my_end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.date) min_date 
         FROM replication_history x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN replication_history y 
           ON y.unitname = x.unitname 
          AND y.date > x.date 
          AND y.percentage = 100 
        WHERE x.percentage < 100 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY unitname
     , my_end;
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| unitname | my_start            | my_end              |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UNIT1    | 2018-01-20 10:15:00 | 2018-01-20 10:25:00 |
| UNIT2    | 2018-01-20 10:05:00 | 2018-01-20 10:10:00 |
| UNIT2    | 2018-01-20 10:15:00 | 2018-01-20 10:25:00 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a large data set and this wasn't as quick as the 'Gaps-and-islands' approach.